# Графика на С++

Tags: directx, c++, opengl

Есть задание: написать программу с графическим интерфейсом. Использовать С++ в связке с OpenGL или DirectX.

Подскажите, где можно достать информацию по данной теме.

Answer (score 10):

По связке C++/DirectX качественный источник информации - это MSDN.

- [Создание игрового приложения](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb384840.aspx)
- [DirectX SDK Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/directx/ee623005)

[DirectX Tutorial](http://www.directxtutorial.com/) - неплохой ресурс.

Кроме того:

- На [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/) есть примеры с кодом.
- На [GameDev](http://nehe.gamedev.net/) есть примеры по OpenGL.
- Много полезной инфомации на [gamedev.ru](http://gamedev.ru).

Comment: По поводу видео уроков на gamedev, http://pmg.org.ru/nehe/index.html тут они полностью переведены
Да и вобще по мне самый лучший русскоязычный сайт по OpenGl

Comment: @username76, беда в том, что уроки от NeHe хоть и отличные, но безнадежно устаревшие :(

Answer (score 4):

[Qt](http://qt-project.org/) Вам в помощь

Comment: зря человека заминусовали, в Qt есть обёртка над OpenGL, QGLWidget, которая берёт на себя инициализацию графического контекста и тому подобные вещи, очень удобно для новичков.

Comment: Причём, начиная с Qt 5.0, старый-добрый QGLWidget считается deprecated, новое АПИ для работы с OGL - QWindow + OpenGLSurface:
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtgui-index.html#opengl-and-opengl-es-integration
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwindow.html
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qopenglcontext.html
Пример: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtgui-openglwindow-example.html

Answer (score 3):

http://www.opengl.org/
Официальный сайт, тут просто должно быть МОРЕ информации, естественно на английском).
Вроде бы на NeHe были уроки, но у меня с ними ничего не вышло.
Русскоязычные ресурсы это геймдев.

Answer (score 0):

Есть ещё некое `unity`. Есть и `opengl` для `c#`, и многое другое. Вдруг пригодится:)

Comment: Как OpenGL для C# неплохо смотрится [Mono + Cairo](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T%3aCairo.GlitzSurface).

Answer (score 0):

Для начала рекомендуется использовать opengl, так как он попроще и компактней.

Вот полный рабочий пример самого простого приложения.
Используется библиотека SDL. Для opengl это тоже, что и STL для С++.
Предоставляет удобный обработчик событий, работу со звуком, устройствами.

Ссылка на [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/download-1.2.php).

Рисует красный квадрат на чёрном фоне.

```
#define МАКСИМУМ_КНОПОК 423
bool нажатые_кнопки[МАКСИМУМ_КНОПОК];

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

#include <sdl/include/SDL.h>
#include <sdl/include/SDL_mixer.h>
#include <sdl/include/SDL_syswm.h>
#undef main

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

#pragma comment (lib , "sdl.lib")

int ширина_экрана = 1920;
int высота_экрана = 1080;

bool приложение_выполняется = true;

int OnEvent(SDL_Event* Event)
{
if(Event->type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
{
std::cout << "\nsym=" << (int)Event->key.keysym.sym;
нажатые_кнопки[Event->key.keysym.sym] = true; }
if(Event->type == SDL_KEYUP){нажатые_кнопки[Event->key.keysym.sym] = false; }
return true;
}

// события
SDL_Event Event;
inline void events(){while(SDL_PollEvent(&Event)){OnEvent(&Event);}}

void base_draw()
{
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  glColor4f(1,1,1,1);// важно
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  glOrtho(0.0, ширина_экрана, 0.0, высота_экрана, -1550000, 1500000);
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}

int глубина_цвета = 32;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
std::system("chcp 1251");

SDL_Surface * Surf_Display = NULL;
if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_AUDIO) < 0) {return 0;}
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_SWAP_CONTROL, 0);

  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
  glLoadIdentity();

  unsigned int flags =  SDL_OPENGL | SDL_RESIZABLE;
  if((Surf_Display = SDL_SetVideoMode(ширина_экрана, высота_экрана, глубина_цвета, flags)) == NULL){return 0;}

  glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // цвет экрана при очищении

  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  glColor4f(1,1,1,1);// важно
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  glLoadIdentity();
  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

while(приложение_выполняется==true)
{
events();
base_draw();

glColor4ub(255, 0, 0, 255);
glRectd(500 , 500 , 1000 , 1000);

SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();
};

std::system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Кошмар. Названия переменных по-русски :-o

Comment: Opa 1C style

    int ширина_экрана = 1920;
    int высота_экрана = 1080;